# While loop should put out concated strings, only output in console and not concated? Ruby MongoDB Sinatra

Tags: ruby, mongodb, loops, while-loop, sinatra

I´m looping through an array and I want each part of the array to be displayed in my browser. While it finds the right entries and puts them in the console it won´t show them in the browser. I can make the first one or last one appear on the screen but not all of them concated together.

```
while x < entrysize do

  found = " "

  if entry = entries.shift

    firstname = entry["firstname"]
    lastname = entry["lastname"]
    number = entry["number"]
    x += 1

    found += "Found #{entrysize} entries: <br><br>Name: #{firstname} #{lastname}<br><br>Number: #{number}<br><br><a href='/'>Back</a><br>"
    puts found

  else
    #if there are no entries display this message
    "Sorry, no entries found!"
  end


end
found
```

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the > found = " " outside of the while loop, that did it right away!

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mistake to think that `puts` will render the string to the HTTP response and eventually to the browser. This code will only print hello to the console:

```
get '/' do
  puts 'hello, world!'
end
```

What you want, however, is to return the string that should be rendered from the `do ... end` block. Since Ruby will implicitly return the value of the last statement, you could just write:

```
get '/' do
  'hello, world!'
end
```

In your specific case, the problem is that you are overwriting `found` with `" "` on every iteration, also the last one. However, your code also has different problems I highly recommend using a view to build the HTML output, [which is explained in detail here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates).

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I´m painfully aware of that. I had to put the 
> found = " "
outside of the while loop, that did it right away! So you helped me after all, thank you:)